# extract substring with Awk linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk

I have file with this content :

```
Text1 , Text11  : APC signal 0 , prev=7
Text2 , Text22  : APC signal 1 , prev=0
Text3 , Text33  : APC signal 0 , prev=1
Text4 , Text44  : APC signal 1 , prev=0
Text5 , Text55  : APC signal 0 , prev=1
Text6 , Text66  : APC signal 1 , prev=0
```

I want to extract the first and the third column, but just a substring of second column (second part after ":")  :

the Result i want :

```
Text1 ,  APC signal 0 , prev=7
Text2 ,  APC signal 1 , prev=0
Text3 ,  APC signal 0 , prev=1
Text4 ,  APC signal 1 , prev=0
Text5 ,  APC signal 0 , prev=1
Text6 ,  APC signal 1 , prev=0
```

Comment: Please accept the `sed` answer. That answer is concise and better than mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, '{sub(/.*:/, "", $2); }1' OFS="," file
Text1 , APC signal 0 , prev=7
Text2 , APC signal 1 , prev=0
Text3 , APC signal 0 , prev=1
Text4 , APC signal 1 , prev=0
Text5 , APC signal 0 , prev=1
Text6 , APC signal 1 , prev=0
```

The built-in `awk` function [sub](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) works as
`sub(regexp, replacement [, target])`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
sed 's/, [^:]*:/, /' file
```

This searches for text starting with a comma and space (`,` ), followed by as much as possible that isn't a colon (`[^:]*`), and then a colon itself (`:`). It then replaces that with a comma and space (`,` ) to get your required output:

```
Text1 ,  APC signal 0 , prev=7
Text2 ,  APC signal 1 , prev=0
Text3 ,  APC signal 0 , prev=1
Text4 ,  APC signal 1 , prev=0
Text5 ,  APC signal 0 , prev=1
Text6 ,  APC signal 1 , prev=0
```

If you don't actually want the two spaces shown after the first comma change the second occurrence of comma space (`,` ) to just a single comma (`,`).

Answer (score 0):

Like this using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
$ awk -F' , | : ' -vOFS=' , ' '{print $1, $3, $4}' file
-------8<------------------
Text1 , APC signal 0 , prev=7
Text2 , APC signal 1 , prev=0
Text3 , APC signal 0 , prev=1
Text4 , APC signal 1 , prev=0
Text5 , APC signal 0 , prev=1
Text6 , APC signal 1 , prev=0
```